# How to remove statements form Django query_utils Q?

Tags: python, django

I know how to chain together certain filters for my qs.

```
from django.db.models import Q

f = models.Q(public=True)

f |= models.Q(owner=user)

f == models.Q(public=True) | models.Q(owner=user)
```

I also want to remove certain filters, but I don't know how. Something like this:

```
f -= models.Q(owner=user)
```

Comment: I don't think you want a double equality here `f == models.Q(public=True) | models.Q(owner=user)`

Comment: The == is just there to showcase my point. It doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
f = models.Q(public=True) | ~models.Q(owner=user)
```

the `~` means `NOT`